# SQLite Transaction Fail

Tags: android, sqlite

i am working on sqlite insertion using contentvalues with transaction . The following code does not generate any exception however the data is not inserted.

Did i miss somethings ? Thanks.

```
public boolean addRecord(Rec rec) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.beginTransaction();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_ID, rec.get());

    // Inserting Row
    try {
        db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_RECORDS, null, values);
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }  
db.endTransaction();
    db.close();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Have you trace at your stack trace? If not then go for it. . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After calling [beginTransaction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction%28%29), you *must* call [setTransactionSuccessful](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#setTransactionSuccessful%28%29) to ensure that the transaction gets committed. Without that call, any changes in the transaction are rolled back.

```java
db.beginTransaction();
try {
  ...
  db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
  db.endTransaction();
}
```

This particular construction ensures that any exception in the actual database code will result in an rollback.

(If you get an exception, it is a bad idea to just swallow it; the entire function must fail.)